# How do I force Bundler to get the right libv8-node for mini-racer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, libv8

I'm working on a Rails 5->6 update. When I run `bundle update`, we reach mini_racer, which requires libv8-node. When Bundler tries to get libv8-node v. 15.14.0.1, it tries to install `<our local mirror path>/gems/gems-repos/gems/libv8-node-15.14.0.1-x86_64-linux-musl.gem`, which is incorrect (this is a Debian VM) and the server responds with an error. `gem install libv8-node` works just fine.

The ruby-libv8-node page [suggests there is a known issue with Bundler picking the wrong platform](https://github.com/sqreen/ruby-libv8-node#note-on-alpinemusl). Chasing down that rabbit hole it looks like there are proposed solutions but nothing released yet.

In the meantime, is there a workaround for forcing Bundler to use the right platform? This is Bundler 2.2.28 and Ruby 2.6.6.

Comment: did you first try `gem uninstall libv8-node`  ?

Comment: @lacostenycoder I did, and it does not help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the README, it says

> If a published binary does not work for you, bundler allows to force using the ruby platform via force_ruby_platform, which will compile from source.

so please try

`BUNDLE_FORCE_RUBY_PLATFORM=1 bundle install`

or `BUNDLE_FORCE_RUBY_PLATFORM=1 bundle update rails`

Comment: That got me a successful `bundle update` (albeit super slow, as did some source compiling of other gems as well). Progress! This may be it!

Answer (score 5):

I've been dealing with this problem today. Whilst enabling the BUNDLE_FORCE_RUBY_PLATFORM=1 environment variable for bundler will work because it compiles from source, however this will be **slow**. Compiling libv8-node is no small chunk of code.

An alternative that worked for me was

`BUNDLE_SPECIFIC_PLATFORM=1 bundle install`

and that pulled the correct pre-compiled x86_64-linux binary for libv8-node. Much faster.

Note, I had already added x86_64-linux to the PLATFORMS section of the lockfile using `bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux`. This is the right thing to do anyway, but I'm not able to say for sure whether the `BUNDLE_SPECIFIC_PLATFORM` alone was sufficient to resolve or whether it was the combination.